# What's the point of c# memory pool?

Tags: c#, pointers, memory, memory-management, buffer

I get the concept of `ArrayPools`.
But I don't quite understand why to use `MemoryPools` (C#). A `Memory<T>` represents a contiguous region of memory, like a (more complex) pointer. My thought is, that there is no need of pooling when directly pointing to an adress. Afaik nothing has to be allocated (except the overhead)? But the existence of this Struct indicates that there is a reason...so what is it? (googled/stackoverflowed but did not found sth. enlighting)

To make it plastic :
What is the disadvantage in this use-scenario without an arraypool?

```
var arr = new double[100];
var mem = arr.AsMemory(0,100);
```

vs

```
var pool = MemoryPool<double>;
var owner = pool.Shared;
var arr = new double[100];
var mem = owner.Rent(100);
mem = arr.AsMemory(0,100);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `Memory<T>` needs some memory to point to, and this memory needs to be allocated.

A MemoryPool is a place to rent pre-allocated memory. It is not an actual `Memory<T>` you are renting, but the memory it points to. Note that MemoryPool give you a `IMemoryOwner<T>`, i.e. an object that represents the actual ownership of the underlying memory, and you need to get your `Memory<T>` from this interface.

Objects larger than ~87kb (unless the limit has been changed) are allocated on the large object heap (LOH). This is only collected in gen 2 collections, that are much slower then gen 0 collections. The LOH is also not automatically defragmented, possibly leading till fragmentation issues if it is over used. Because of this it is recommended to use a memory pool when frequently allocating and deallocating large buffers.

So in your example it is of no advantage to use a memory pool. But it could for example be useful when working with hundreds of multi-megabyte images in a webserver.

Also, your example makes no sense, it should look something like

```
using var owner = MemoryPool<double>.Shared.Rent(100); // Use the singleton pool
Memmory<double> mem = owner.Memory;
```

Comment: Ok,. 
- you can allocate memory
But when do you need this kind of behaviour?

To make it plastic I added my main post with a scenario...

Comment: @c_ph_r because frequent allocation/de allocation of large buffers strain the GC, forcing slow gen 2 collections. Using a memory pool avoid this issue, since renting/returning a pooled object is cheap, and may also help avoid memory fragmentation. But the usage is fairly situational, so don't go overusing pools just because it is faster in some specific situations.

Comment: The Memory<T> object has to be allocated, but the content of the array in the above example is already allocated and the Memory<T> object points to it. IMHO it makes no difference for the size of the Memory<T> object if its pointing to a small or huge array. ? So you talk about the allocation of the Memory<T> objects themself? Thank you for the lucid answers so far!!

Comment: @c_ph_r your example makes no sense at all, See update.